# I believe this game uses websocket but my Override of WebSocket does not work?

Tags: javascript, flash, google-chrome, websocket, greasemonkey

Many popular web games are created in Flash.  I'm fairly certain they also take advantage of websockets to do tasks like chat and constant updates.  The game in question, though really I'd like to be able to do this to all of them, is Dragons of Atlantis.  This game uses both XMLHTTPRequests for actions and I believe a websocket which I found in the flash parameters here:

```
    <object id="castlemania_swf" width="760" height="800" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/castlemania-production/flash/game/current/preloader.swf?cachebreaker=23423423429">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
<param name="flashvars" value="session_id=fjdkfjal2j3j2lkj232&locale=en&api_server=http://realm193.c10.castle.wonderhill.com/api&pub_server=c10.castle.wonderhill.com&pub_port=7000&user_id=89234787492&user_hash=242343234242342432342343424232&user_time=1344028407&dragon_heart=234343242432432432432342432&platform=yahoofb&subnetwork=&s3_server=https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/castlemania-production&s3_swf_prefix=/flash/game/current&assets_server=https://assets-castle.wonderhill.com&assets_prefix=/flash/gam...ode_is_cdn=false&preloader_cachebreaker=243234432423&primary_ui_cachebreaker=23432432&secondary_ui_cachebreaker=24322432423&i18n_cachebreaker=2432423342432&manifest_cachebreaker=24342423423&building_cachebreaker=23423423342&sound_cachebreaker=2432423342423&client_cachebreaker=2432423342423&lazy_loaded_swf_cachebreaker=2432432423&map_bin_cachebreaker=24342323&assets_cachebreaker=2432432423_2423423423.24323423&statics_translations_cachebreaker=20130305_213355.49364792&statics_manifests_cachebreaker=243223423234_213429.42776785">
```

So you don't have to search here is the params I'm interested in

```
    api_server=http://realm193.c10.castle.wonderhill.com/api&pub_server=c10.castle.wonderhill.com&pub_port=7000
```

I am using greasemonkey and firefox after trying to use Chrome and seeing no evidence of a websocket being sniffed by the browser developer tools and Overrided the WebSocket

```
    (function(){
var proxied=window.WebSocket.prototype.send;
window.WebSocket.prototype.send=function(){
    alert(arguments[0]);
    return proxied.apply(this,[].slice.call(arguments));
};
    })();
```

Still no luck although it does work great for all html5 based applications.  Is flash bypassing the browser and this is why Chrome/Firefox/Javascript doesn't pick up the websocket calls.  **Is there a way to work with the websockets that flash does use?**  My goal is not only to sniff the traffic but use it in a meaningful way so simply seeing the traffic is not sufficient.  Thanks for any help!!

(I know a popular answer to websockets is use Chrome but in this case it simply does not work with the default Chrome thanks!)

Comment: Can flash really send a handshake and headers without the browser detecting it?? Is this not a potential security risk if it's the case?

Comment: If the game is written in Flash, it probably does not use the `WebSocket` object exposed to JS. However, you should be able to see the requests in the network panel of the devtools.

Comment: Btw, you forgot a `.prototype` in `proxied=window.WebSocket.send`.

Comment: @Bergi as I tried to communicate it does not show up in Google Chrome network panel of the devtools.  I know this a common answer and I've thoroughly checked and checked again.  There are no requests are captured.  In otherwords the number of requests located at the bottom does not increment at all.  However wireshark and fiddler do pick up traffic where Chrome sits idle.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for pointing out the missing prototype I'm really not a javascript programmer and completely new the code I had was from XMLHTTPRequest Override else where in this forum.  I tested it and made the updates to this and my userscript.

Comment: Flash Player/ActionScript has its own implementation of socket communication (has had for about 10 years, predating websockets). I'm no expert on the subject, but as I understand it, websockets normally use the standard HTTP port 80 (or 443 for HTTPS) , whereas ActionScript sockets normally use some other port, not the HTTP standard ones. The URL in your case specifies port 7000, which could indicate it is probably not for websockets, if I understand things right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flash as a socket gateway for javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612471/flash-as-a-socket-gateway-for-javascript)